# (Python, MySQL) How can I assign a variable to a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a piece of code like this:

```
isbn = 4567
c.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE Book_d = %s;",(isbn,))
search = c.fetchone()
print(search)
```

But I want to change the attribute to a variable like this:

```
isbn = 4567
bisbn = 'Book_d'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE %s = %s;",(bisbn, isbn,))
search = c.fetchone()
print(search)
```

But I guess the syntax is wrong here.

I just wanted to ask whether it is possible to do something like this and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to 'prepare' that kind of variable, so you can use a regular variable (whatever that looks like in python). That said, this kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: you have to string concat bisbn  and then use your first query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this.

```
isbn = 4567
bisbn = 'Book_d'
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE %s = %s;"%(bisbn, isbn,)
```

Or if you are using python3

```
sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM book WHERE {bisbn} = {isbn}"
print(sql_query)
```